# Deleted question not visible

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-answers, deleted-questions

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4121391/jeremy) asked a question yesterday which I answered (at least, I answered the bits that were clear enough to answer).

The question, along with my answer, seems to have been deleted now and he's asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262617/apex-oracle-custom-login-script) (having fixed the issues that I raised).

Not that I really care one way or another, but just wondering why I can't see the deleted question (as my rep is >10k)?

Comment: Thanks. I did a search on my feedly and found a link to the deleted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only see a deleted post if you have a direct link to it. You won't find it in the profile of the question asker or listed in searches or tag pages anymore.

Your answer will be listed in your personal *deleted recent answers* list (linked from the bottom of [your answers tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103295/jeffrey-kemp?tab=answers) in your profile).